# Calculating and extracting pixel coordinates of rectangle corners in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, coordinates

I have the following snippet of my script that draws a rectangle around an image feature based on the x/y coords of the centerpoint and the radius (r):

```
for index, row in img1_df.iterrows():
    for i in range(len(img1_df)):
        draw.rectangle(((float(row['x'])-float(row['r']), float(row['y'])-float(row['r'])), (float(row['x'])+float(row['r']), float(row['y'])+float(row['r']))), fill=(255,0,0,55))
```

Illustrated here:

[image]

However, I now wish to extract the pixel coordinate values of the 4 corners of the rectangle. How do I do so from the available data? Furthermore, how do I then append this new corner coordinate data into a new column (or preferably 4 new columns, one for each corner) in the existing daframe comprising the "x", "y", and "r" values?

Thanks, R

Comment: what is your actual question? you already have 2 corner coordinates. the other two can be calculated by simple addition.

Comment: Do I? Which ones, top left and bottom right? And how then do I extract these two values so that I can refer to them to calculate the remaining two sides?